# How to set up GH codespace to be able to use postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, github-codespaces

I am a newbie to codespaces and to docker. I want a codespace environment with postgres installed so that I can use the command line to create and play around with simple SQL commands to make a database, create a table, add some data, do some select queries, that kind of thing.
I don't really need more than this but being able to use node.js would be cool too.
Questions - is this even possible on codespace? If so how? I have tried searching for a guide or video aimed at beginners but can't find anything.
If anyone can point me in the right direction or even at a github repo that I could clone that does this that would be amazing!
Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you just want to mess around with PostgreSQL directly, try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Dev Containers extension to Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) to add a predefined container configuration to your codespace.

[image]

See [Introduction to Dev Containers: Using a Predefined Dev Container Configuration](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/adding-a-dev-container-configuration/introduction-to-dev-containers#using-a-predefined-dev-container-configuration).

Comment: this extension doesn't work on github codespaces in the online version of VS code. thanks though

Comment: @RonSouthin You can use the app, it's free and works on everything; it's the general purpose ide I recommend. But you can do what it's doing manually, read the Introduction document I linked to.